# Why is this do/until loop exiting with values starting 1?

Tags: powershell

Built a menu system which for the most part works fine but I've hit a weird validation error and I'm scratching my head as to why this function is escaping when you answer with "11" (or indeed any number starting with 1)

```bsh
function Get-MenuSelection {

    $totalOptions = 2

    do {
        $input = Read-Host "[1 <-> $totalOptions | (Q)uit - FIRST]"
        while (!$input) {
            $input = Read-Host "[1 <-> $totalOptions | (Q)uit - LOOP]"
        }

    } until ($input -lt $totalOptions -or $input -eq $totalOptions -or $input -eq "q")

Write-Host "exiting"
}

Get-MenuSelection
```

Output I'm getting:

```
./wtf.ps1
[1 <-> 2 | (Q)uit - FIRST]: 
[1 <-> 2 | (Q)uit - LOOP]: 
[1 <-> 2 | (Q)uit - LOOP]: test
[1 <-> 2 | (Q)uit - FIRST]: 22
[1 <-> 2 | (Q)uit - FIRST]: 9090
[1 <-> 2 | (Q)uit - FIRST]: 11
exiting
```

I'm clearly doing something wrong but just can't figure out what.

**Solution**

For those reading this some time in the future, I ended up with this - I chose to drop the 'q' options since it was just over-complicating the logic. Thanks to @AdminofThings and @mklement0 for the input. Appreciated.

```bsh
function Get-MenuSelection {
    param (
        $output 
    )

    [int]$totalOptions = $output.Count
    do {
        try { [int]$answer = Read-Host "Options: [1 <-> $totalOptions]" }
        catch { }

        if ($answer -eq "0" -or $answer -gt $totalOptions) { 
            Write-Host "Invalid input detected. Ctrl+C to quit." 
        }
    } while ($answer -gt $totalOptions -or !$answer)

    $returnedAnswer = "menu_$answer"
    return $returnedAnswer
}
```

Comment: `$input` is a string and `$totaloptions` is an int. You need to change your until condition to use `[int]$input`. The other option is to flip your comparisons so that the int is on the left side, i.e. `$totaloptions -gt $input`. In these situations, PowerShell will convert the righthand side to be the same type as the lefthand side.

Comment: As an aside: automatic variable `$input` not only shouldn't be used for custom purposes, it actually _doesn't work_: while you can (ostensibly) _set_  it, the assigned value is ignored, and when you _get_ it, you always get an empty enumerator (outside of contexts where Powershell defines `$input` for you).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `$input` is an automatic/reserved variable, your code will not execute as intended. `$input` will likely result in an empty value during retrieval.

If we theoretically assume that `$input` is replaced by something that is not reserved, then a corresponding issue here is `$input` is a string and `$totaloptions` is an int. When PowerShell is faced with a comparison operation and both sides of the comparison don't match types, it will attempt to convert the righthand side (RHS) type to match the lefthand side (LHS). To get around this, you need to either cast `$input` as an `[int]` or bring `$totaloptions` to the LHS.

```
until ([int]$input -lt $totalOptions -or $input -eq $totalOptions -or $input -eq "q")
# OR
until ($totalOptions -gt $input -or $input -eq $totalOptions -or $input -eq "q")
```

**An example of your situation:**

```
#Unexpected Outcome
> [string]11 -lt [int]2
True

#Expected Outcome
> [int]11 -lt [int]2
False

#Expected Outcome
> [int]2 -gt [string]11
False
```